# Is this a gas pipe?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, gas

I removed my tub (2nd floor bathroom)to replace it with a jetted tub and I need more room width wise so I decided to knock part of the wall out to slide the edge of the new tub into to make clearance for the door to close.

I knocked out part of the wall and noticed a pipe looks black but maybe rusty but not sure. I am wondering if this is a gas or water pipe.

I know the light in kitchen was gas a lifetime ago but has been capped off also there was a stove in the adjacent bedroom.

[image]

[image]

Comment: All we can say is that it's iron pipe. It's up to you to see where it goes. Since there's only one it's more likely that it's gas, but how can we tell from here?

Comment: " light in the kitchen was gas"; do you mean the house had gas lighting ? If that is what you mean , it may or may not have gas in it.  Our apartment in Chicago originally had gas lights ; I remember my father complaining that some lines had been disconnected but some still had gas.

Comment: It appears open, if so do not worry about it. If you can trace to the other end and if you can remove it. Then cap or plug the line for safety, you never know there might be a valve that is elsewhere and somebody opens it saying what is this?

Comment: `Is this a gas pipe?` can only be answered by you or someone you hire to find out .... `could it be a gas pipe?` always has a `yes` answer